# Kotlin generics for functions in parameter and return type

Tags: kotlin, generics

everyone!
I have some class from Java dependency:

```
public class MyClass {
   public MyClass copy() {
      ....
   }
   public void init() {
      ...
   }
}
```

And I want to write a function in my Kotlin class:

```
fun <T : MyClass> prepareListCopy(objects: List<T>?): List<T>? =
        objects?.map { it.copy().apply { init() } }
```

I want my function to accept and return List of subtypes of MyClass, but IDE shows me this error:
**Change return type of enclosing function 'KOtlinClass.prepareListCopy' to 'List< MyClass >?'**

How can I correctly define generic in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition you provided, `MyClass.copy()` returns `MyClass`. So even when you have a subtype (say `MySubClass`) and you call `MySubClass.copy()` you will still get a `MyClass`, not a `MySubClass`.

This is why you cannot say your generic function returns a `List<T>?`, you have to say it returns `List<MyClass>?`:

```kotlin
fun <T : MyClass> prepareListCopy(objects: List<T>?): List<MyClass>? =
        objects?.map { it.copy().apply { init() } }
```

(which is exactly what the error message is telling you :D)

Now given what this function does, there is no real point in knowing the exact `T` anymore, you could just accept a `List<MyClass>` (`List` is covariant in its type argument in Kotlin), and the function doesn't need to be generic:

```kotlin
fun prepareListCopy(objects: List<MyClass>?): List<MyClass>? =
        objects?.map { it.copy().apply { init() } }
```

---

If all implementations of all subclasses of `MyClass` guarantee that `copy()` returns the same subtype as the current instance (and if the documentation of `copy()` imposes it by contract), then you could also make your extension reified and add a safe cast:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : MyClass> prepareListCopy(objects: List<T>?): List<T>? =
        objects?.map { it.copy().apply { init() } as T }
```

Comment: (Drat, only 20 seconds away from posting a very similar answer, and you beat me to it…  :-)

Comment: @gidds haha, classic! This happens to me more often than I'd like to admit :D

Comment: @Joffrey So I will have to manually cast my List<MyClass> in callsite to List<MuSubClass>?

Comment: @Joffrey IDEA underlines out in List<out MyClass> and prints: "Projection is redundant: the correcsponding type parameter of List has the same variance"

Comment: @Wazuuuuup oh of course, I somehow forgot `List` is already covariant in Kotlin. I edited the answer, you indeed don't need `out`.

Comment: @Wazuuuuup *So I will have to manually cast my List<MyClass> in callsite to List<MuSubClass>?* - no, that would not be correct. The java class doesn't guarantee that `copy()` returns the same subtype of `MyClass` as the current instance (maybe it happens in practice but in theory it doesn't guarantee it with its type system). Does the documentation of `copy()` guarantee this by contract?

Comment: It'd probably be better to change the Java class so that `copy()` returned the appropriate subclass type.  This would be easy if Java (and Kotlin) had a ‘self’ type; instead, the usual way is to use the [curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); see e.g. [this question](/questions/2165613/java-generic-type).

Comment: Yeah I guess it's safe to assume from the function name that this should already be guaranteed, but it's just not expressed via generics in Java. I'm under the assumption the Java code is third-party and not modifiable here, but maybe that was a wrong assumption indeed :D